# Complex Eloquent Relation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple ticketing system. Lets say, I am fetching a ticket, and all the relations to it.
A ticket can have multiple `replies`, as well as multiple `attachments`.

```
$ticket = Ticket::with('replies')
                    ->with('attachments')
                    ->find($id);
```

Similarly every `reply` will have a `user_id`, and hence fetch the details for the user.

This is where the trick is.

I cannot think of a way to do that other than looping though each of the replies and manually fetching user details for each reply.

But I believe there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your query as below with a new relation in `replies` model, let it be `userDetails`

```
$ticket = Ticket::find($id)
->with([
    'replies',
    'replies.userDetails',
    'attachments'
]);
```

Comment: 'replies.userDetails' return replies and users table data. No need to use 'replies' separately

Answer (score 2):

Add `belongsTo` relation with user table in your Reply model.

```
$ticket = Ticket::with('replies.user', 'attachments')->find($id);
```

And if you want to show list of all replies, you can use

```
$replies = Reply::with('user')->get();
```